# Tv Tunner card drivers/software in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, tv

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I have problems with the TV card. 
I have this TV card is SAA7130 Video Broadcast Decoder Techcom  TV  Card SSD-TV-670

[image]

*Where/how can I install its drivers and software?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/), it may be useful to you for this.